# LOG4J add some prefix in the log line to indicate the log is truncated

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

due to space limitation i am truncating all log lines with pattern layout

```
<pattern>%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%level{WARN=W, DEBUG=D, ERROR=E, TRACE=T, INFO=I}] %X{RequestId} (%t) %c{2}: %.-10m%n%ex</pattern>
```

However, sometimes its confusing to see if a line of log is truncated or not, and is inconvenient for debugging. Is it possible to add a prefix to log lines that are truncated?

e.g.:

Original: `log more than ten chars`

Before:`log more t`

After: `truncated-log more than t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be done by using the `ScriptPatternSelector` as documented in the log4j2 manual under [PatternLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout). You can set up your selector to choose the pattern based on the length of the formatted message string. Below is sample code to demonstrate.

Here is the log4j2.xml config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="maxMsgLength">10</Property>
        <Property name="basePattern">%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%level{WARN=W, DEBUG=D, ERROR=E, TRACE=T, INFO=I}] %X{RequestId} (%t) %c{2}: %.-${maxMsgLength}m%n%ex</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <ScriptPatternSelector>
                    <Script name="Selector" language="javascript"><![CDATA[
                      if(logEvent.getMessage().getFormattedMessage().length() > ${maxMsgLength}){
                        "P1";
                      }else{
                        "P2";
                      }
                      ]]>
                    </Script>
                    <PatternMatch key="P1" pattern="Truncated ${basePattern}"/>
                    <PatternMatch key="P2" pattern="${basePattern}"/>
                </ScriptPatternSelector>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Here's a Java class to generate some log messages:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class SomeClass {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        log.info("Here's a long message!");
        log.info("Short msg");
    }
}
```

Lastly here is the output from the above:

```
Truncated 20 Jul 2021 22:47:34,531 [I]  (main) example.SomeClass: Here's a l
20 Jul 2021 22:47:34,641 [I]  (main) example.SomeClass: Short msg
```